# Angular Firebase retrieving collected data from anonymous users

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, firebase

I have a survey system using Angular and Firebase which stores the results of users answers inside of an object specific to each user. This works well for storing data, but I've realized that it may be difficult to pull the data back out due to each object having a unique name.

I'd like to loop over each object and pull the all of the values together. So for all 50 entries find the total of comprehension.icons.damage[1]

How can I construct a loop that goes over objects with unique names like the objects below?

Here is my json structure

```
  "usersanonymous:-JgTyGt6An3WWyLvnnuu" : {
"comprehension" : {
  "-JgTzC0r_H58n7y8Al_-" : {
    "date" : 1422154060632,
    "icons" : [ {
      "damage" : [ null, "0", "3", "3" ],
      "ocular" : [ null, "2", "3", "1" ],
      "physical therapy" : [ null, "0", "4", "4" ],
      "skin" : [ null, "4", "0", "1" ]
    } ]
  }
}


 },
  "usersanonymous:-JgU-ryIpI-HR7D4VDkp" : {
    "comprehension" : {
      "-JgU0MwBwisNbjvRFGOT" : {
        "date" : 1422154629142,
        "icons" : [ {
          "damage" : [ null, "0", "3", "4" ],
          "ocular" : [ null, "1", "4", "3" ],
          "physical therapy" : [ null, "2", "4", "3" ],
          "skin" : [ null, "4", "1", "3" ]
        } ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your input data, I would create a function to extract just the data you're interested in.  I've written this in raw javascript - if you're using jQuery you may have fun using $.map rather than for (x in y).

```
var data = {
    "usersanonymous:-JgTyGt6An3WWyLvnnuu": {
        "comprehension": {
            "-JgTzC0r_H58n7y8Al_-": {
                "date": 1422154060632,
                "icons": [{
                    "damage": [null, "0", "3", "3"],
                    "ocular": [null, "2", "3", "1"],
                    "physical therapy": [null, "0", "4", "4"],
                    "skin": [null, "4", "0", "1"]
                }]
            }
        }
    },
    "usersanonymous:-JgU-ryIpI-HR7D4VDkp": {
        "comprehension": {
            "-JgU0MwBwisNbjvRFGOT": {
                "date": 1422154629142,
                "icons": [{
                    "damage": [null, "0", "3", "4"],
                    "ocular": [null, "1", "4", "3"],
                    "physical therapy": [null, "2", "4", "3"],
                    "skin": [null, "4", "1", "3"]
                }]
            }
        }
    }
};

function extractComprehension(rawData) {
    var result = [];

    for (var usersanonymous in rawData) {
        usersanonymous = rawData[usersanonymous];
        if (usersanonymous.comprehension) {
            for (var token in usersanonymous.comprehension) {
                token = usersanonymous.comprehension[token];
                if (token.icons) {
                    result.push(token.icons[0]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

function sumOf(objectList, property, index) {
    var result = 0;

    for (var o in objectList) {
        var numbers = (objectList[o][property] || []);

        if (numbers.length >= index) {
            result += parseInt(numbers[index], 10);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Using this mini api you can get the sum of the properties you're interested in:

```
// Get the data array.
var comprehension = extractComprehension(data);

// Sum some property.
console.log(sumOf(comprehension, 'damage', 3));
```